# Get the greatest value in a nvarchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm developing a database with SQL Server 2012 SP2.

I have a table with a NVARCHAR(20) column, and it will have numbers: "000001", "000002", etc.

I need to get the greatest value in that column and convert it to int. How can I do it?

I have found that I can convert a nvarchar to int with this sql sentence:
`SELECT CAST(YourVarcharCol AS INT) FROM Table`

But I don't know how can I get the max value in that column because the numbers are nvarchar.

**UPDATE:**

By the way, this column is NVARCHAR because I need to store text on it. I'm testing my solution and I need to store **ONLY** numbers to test it.

Comment: SELECT top 1 CAST(YourVarcharCol AS INT) as ival FROM Table order by ival desc

Comment: Use this '
select  max(cast(ColumnName AS INT ))from TableName'

Comment: In any case, it'd be interesting to know what's your ultimate goal and why you need to calculate the maximum value of a numeric string because there may be better solutions.

Comment: Any reason why you have stored a numeric value as a text in the database? Do you support non-numeric values? Be aware that an index on this column will probably not be used since the alphanumeric order may not correspond to the numerical order, which means your code is probably going to do a full tablescan on such a query due to this column being text. Are you sure this is the right solution?

Comment: If you are currently developing a new solution I would **strongly** suggest you change the data type of that column to a numeric one, and leave formatting to take care of adding this zeroes on demand.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes, there is a reason. This is because on that column a could store also text. I'm testing my software and at this moment I need to store numbers to test it.

Comment: @VansFannel. The information *that column a could store also text* is something you **really should have added to your initial question** There are 6 answers and **all of them are wrong** now. This is called *chameleon-question* ...

Comment: @Shnugo I don't think that the 6 answers are wrong now.

Comment: @VansFannel, if there are mixed values, any plain `CAST(x AS INT)` will fail...

Comment: You can't cast a non-numeric value to an int without more work. So yes, all of those answers are indeed wrong as they will all crash with an invalid cast error.

Comment: @VansFannel Your update *I need to store ONLY numbers to test it* makes clear, that a plain `CAST` should work. But I strongly recommend to test with *big-data*, if you expect larger amounts. A small scenario *cast-all-and-pick-the-max* will work, but this might be horribly slow with greater count...

Comment: How will the `greatest value` handle text non-numeric values? Is `000001` greater than or less than `ABCDEF` ?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen The column will have only numbers like `000001`, `000002` or letters like `ABCDEF`. But it won't have mixed values like numbers as text and text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your **numbers are padded like in the example given and all have the same width**, you can just sort them **alphanumerically** and then cast the *max-value* to `INT` or `BIGINT` (depending on your numbers range).

If there are very many rows it was **much faster**, especially if there is an index on this column...

Something like

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM YourTable
ORDER BY NumberColumn DESC
```

or, if you need the max-value only:

```
SELECT MAX(NumberColumn) FROM YourTable
```

If you have to **deal with negative numbers** or **differently padded numbers** you have to **cast them first**

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM YourTable
ORDER BY CAST(NumberColumn AS INT) DESC
```

or

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(NumberColumn AS INT)) FROM YourTable
```

Please note:

- If you've got very many rows, the **second might get rather slow**. Read about *sargable*
- If your NumberColumn might include **invalid values**, you have to check, Read about `ISNUMERIC()`.
- The **best solution** - in any case - was to **use an indexed numeric column to store these values**

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the numbers will be padded with the same width. And, no, the won't be negative numbers. What is the second from the second might get rather slow?

Comment: @VansFannel, the first approach is to rely on the alphanumeric sorting (no negatives, all padded to the same width). Put and index on this column and this will be lightning fast. The second approach is a `CAST` on every single value (or `TRY_CAST()`), which will lead to a full table scan and will be very slow...

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SELECT MAX(t.Y) from (SELECT CAST(YourVarcharCol AS INT) as Y FROM Table) t
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one...

I think `MAX` is enough.

```
SELECT max(CAST(YourVarcharCol AS INT)) FROM Table
```

Answer (score 3):

This will return `max int value`

```
SELECT MAX(IIF(ISNUMERIC(YourVarcharCol) = 1, YourVarcharCol, '0') * 1) FROM Table
```

Answer (score 3):

If all the data follow the same padding and formatting pattern, a simple max(col) would do.

However, if not, you have to cast the values to int first. Searching on a columns cast to some other datatype will not use an index, if there's any, but will scan the whole table instead. It may or may not be OK for you, depending on requirements and number of rows in the table. If performance is what you need, then create a calculated column as try_cast( col as int), and create an index on it.

Note that you should not use cast, but try_cast instead, to guard against values that can't be cast (if you use a datatype to store something which is essencially of another datatype, it always opens up a possibility for errors).

Of couse, if you can change the original column's type to int, it would be the best.

Answer (score 2):

You should try this on finding the highest value:

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(YourVarcharCol AS INT)) AS FROM Table
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this

```
select  max(cast(ColumnName AS INT ))from TableName
```